# RTSP to RTMP streaming or something else

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, rtsp, rtmp

I have a RTSP streaming on IP Cameras.I need to publish this cams on the web page.I tried with JWPlayer but I think jwplayer just supports rtmp not rtsp. If there is no support for RTSP on web pages.I need to do convert RTSP to RTMP.
How can I do this ?